# Remove images (with transparency/alpha channel) from PDF

Tags: linux, pdf

How to remove images with alpha channel (transparency) in a PDF file?

I need to remove all images with transparency from a PDF file because it needs to be optimized with `pdf2ps` and `ps2pdf` (to reduce filesize).. Postscript doesn't work properly when the PDF contains images with transparency and the PDF will be converted to one big image..

Comment: When running `gs` on a PDF with alpha channel images and forcing it to remove the transparencies (either by selecting a PDF version < 1.4 or by setting `-dHaveTransparency=false`) results in the entire page stored as bitmap image. OpenOffice can handle this better (try to export a Writer document w/ RGBA image as PDF/A). Why not using `gs`'s pdfwrite to shrink your PDFs and stay at a PDF level that supports transparency?

Comment: I need to remove alpha channel before running `pdf2ps` because postscript doesn't work with it.. using `gs` alone doesn't always give the best results.. Is running `gs` and `pdf2ps/ps2pdf` in parallel and using the file with smallest file size

Comment: Given the fact that there are many PDF features that won't "survive" a PDF→PS→PDF conversion (next to transparent images), I would strongly recommend using `gs`/pdfwrite alone and find out why your resulting PDF files are too large sometimes. pdfwrite has a [ton of options](http://ghostscript.com/doc/current/Ps2pdf.htm) for fine-tuning. That said, I don't think that there is an easy solution to remove transparency from images. Maybe you can write your own solution using a PDF library such as qpdf (see [this example](https://github.com/qpdf/qpdf/blob/master/examples/pdf-invert-images.cc)).

Comment: I "don't care" about PDF features.. I just need the smallest possible filesize and `ps2pdf` is often the far best tool to achieve this.. Have taken a look at your example.. what is it written in?

Comment: If you exclude the `pdfwrite` approach, I think you'll have to write your own program to remove the transparency from images. The example linked above is written in C++ (.cc extension). It demonstrates the manipulation of images using the QPDF library. There is also PoDoFo for object-level PDF manipulation and Poppler for rendering-level PDF handling (Poppler can render to PDF, too.)

Comment: Why is this question tagged [tag:php]?

Comment: Why indeed? I suggested removing the tag in an edit.

Answer (score 1):

I have not managed to reproduce your problem.
For cons, I did the same treatment to compress my pdf except that I used `pdftops` instead of `pdf2ps`.
I hope it will help.
Sorry for my english (translate.google)

Comment: have now tried `pdftops` but it seems like it converts the PDF to one big image like `pdf2ps` does... command: `pdftops in.pdf out.pdf.ps`

Comment: @clarkk: I'm not an expert, but there are [options](http://www.linuxcommand.org/man_pages/pdftops1.html). Maybe you will find your happiness. Otherwise, I think you did well to change method, [pdftops  is better than pdf2ps](http://stefaanlippens.net/pdf2ps_vs_pdftops)

Answer (score 0):

Clark,

It sounds like www.pstill.com will do everything you need and more in one tool.  There is a Linux command line version available for a very reasonable price.  I have used the tool on a few different PDF's for different reasons and it has always worked as advertised.

From their website.

**Putting the 'Portable' back in PDF - PDF to PDF Transcoding**

Your PDF cannot be printed on some printers or processed with some applications? PStill can sanitize, simplify, reprocess, flatten transparency and recompress PDF-Files, this process also known as 'transcoding' create a new PDF that has better compatibility, is often smaller in file size, can be optional encrypted/secured and contain only a uniform set of font types. Fonts can be normalized to plain PostScript Type 1 formats, can be subsetted, missing fonts included and bad fonts repaired/replaced. PStill can detect and remove duplicate elements in the PDF. Text can be converted to outlines which makes it perfect for creating 'fontless' PDF. Transcoding can be used to repair bad PDF or simplify the PDF structure so more limited output devices can process it.

Andrew.

Comment: Have downloaded `http://www.wizards.de/~frank/pstill18434_linux_ia32.tar.gz` but how do I install/compile it?!

Comment: I am not a Linux user.  I downloaded the gz file and opened up the gz file in WinRar.  There is a file called INSTALL and halfway down is a section called *** INSTALLATION PROCEDURE *** that seems to explain how to install it and run it.  If you have a Windows machine available I would first suggest downloading the Windows GUI version and running a few files manually through the converter first to see if the output PDF is meeting your requirements.